# Using django for CLI tool

Tags: python, django, frameworks, command-line-interface

Is there any sense in using Django framework for developing Command Line Interface tool? In my case there won't be any graphical interface. What benefits can I get using it? Or maybe you know any other useful frameworks for CLI? I'd like to put an accent on making HTTP requests with REST API.

UPDATE: Thanks guys! I would like rather to use REST API than create it in my tool.

Comment: pyramid is a good, flexible framework, in which you can easily develop a RESTful API.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

While django is primarily for web apps it has a powerful and easy to use ORM that can be used for CLI apps as well. To use django script as a standalone script without a webserver, all you need to do is to add the following to the top of the file.

```
import os, sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Setup environ
    sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "main.settings")

    # Setup django
    import django
    django.setup()

    # now you can import your ORM models
```

Comment: Should have also added that all other imports appear below this section

Comment: Thanks! it helps me a lot.

Comment: Anyone knows about a blog or a tutorial with deeper information about using django as CLI application ?