# Django store joined table in DB and update when tables change

Tags: python, mysql, django, celery

In my Django (1.9) project I need to construct a table from an expensive `JOIN`. I would therefore like to store the table in the DB and only redo the query if the tables involved in the `JOIN` change. As I need the table as a basis for later `JOIN` operations I definitely want to store it in my database and not in any cache. 
The problem I'm facing is that I'm not sure how to determine whether the data in the tables have changed. Connecting to the `post_save`, `post_delete` signals of the respective models seems not to be right since the models might be updated in bulk via CSV upload and I don't want the expensive query to be fired each time a new row is imported, because the DB table will change right away. My current approach is to check whether the data has changed every certain time interval, which would be perfectly fine for me. For this purpose I use a new thread, which compares the Checksums of the involved tables (see code below) to run this task. As I'm not really familiar with multi threading, especially on web servers I do not now, whether this is acceptable. My questions therefore:

1. Is the threading approach acceptable for running this single task?
2. Would a Distributed Task Queue like [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html) be more appropriate?
3. Is there any way to disconnect a signal for a certain time after it is received, so that a bulk upload does not trigger the signal over and over again?

This is my current code:

```
import threading
from django.apps import apps
from .models import SomeModel

    def check_for_table_change():

        app_label = SomeModel._meta.app_label

        def join():
            """Join the tables and save the resulting table to the DB."""  
            ...

        def get_involved_models(app_label):
            """Get all the models that are involved in the join."""
            ...

        involved_models = get_involved_models(app_label)
        involved_dbtables = tuple(model._meta.db_table for model in involved_models)
        sql = 'CHECKSUM TABLE %s' % ', '.join(involved_dbtables)
        old_checksums = None

        while(True):
            # Get the result of the query as named tuples.
            checksums = from_db(sql, fetch_as='namedtuple') 
            if old_checksums is not None:
                # Compare checksums.
                for pair in zip(checksums, old_checksums):
                    if pair[0].Checksum != pair[1].Checksum:
                        print('db changed, table is rejoined')
                        join()
                        break
            old_checksums = checksums
            time.sleep(60)

    check_tables_thread = threading.Thread()
    check_tables_thread.run = check_for_table_change
    check_tables_thread.start()
```

I'm grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: what is your RDBMS?

Comment: My RDBMS is  MySQL.

Comment: I should mention that I need to construct the `JOIN` statement dynamically based on the models, so just storing the query somewhere in the RDBMS would not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Materialized Views and Postgresql

If you were on postgresql, you could have used what's known as a [Materialized View](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html). Thus you can create a view based on your join and it would exist almost like a real table. This is very different from normal joins where the query needs to be executed each and every time a view is used. Now the bad news. Mysql does not have materialized views.

If you switched to postgresql, you might even find that materialized vies are not needed after all. That's because postgresql can use more than one index per table in queries. Thus your join that seems slow at the moment on mysql might be made to run faster with better use of indexes on Postgresql. Of course this is very dependent on what your structure is like.

### Signals vs Triggers

> The problem I'm facing is that I'm not sure how to determine whether
>   the data in the tables have changed. Connecting to the `post_save`,
>   `post_delete` signals of the respective models seems not to be right
>   since the models might be updated in bulk via CSV upload and I don't
>   want the expensive query to be fired each time a new row is imported,
>   because the DB table will change right away.

As you have rightly determined Django signals isn't the right way. This is the sort of task that is best done at the database level. Since you don't have materialized views, this is a job for triggers. However that's a lot of hard work involved (whether you use triggers or signals)

> Is the threading approach acceptable for running this single task?

Why not use [django as a CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088702/using-django-for-cli-tool) here? Which effectively means a django script is invoked by a cron or executed by some other mechanism independently of your website.

> Would a Distributed Task Queue like Celery be more appropriate?

Very much so. Each time the data changes, you can fire off a task that does the update of the table.

> Is there any way to disconnect a signal for a certain time after it is received, so that a bulk upload does not trigger the signal over and over again?

Keyword here is 'TRIGGER' :-)

### Alternatives.

Having said all that doing a join and physically populating a table is going to be very very slow if your table grows to even a few thousand rows. This is because you will need an elaborate query to determine which records have changed (unless you used a separate queue for that). You would then need to insert or update the records in the 'join table' generally update/insert is slower than retrieve so as the size of the data goes, this would become progressively worse.

The real solution maybe to optimize your queries and or tables. May I suggest you post a new question with the slow query and also share your table structures?

Comment: I have indeed been thinking about switching to Postgres for some time. That sounds like a reason more to do it. I'll check out if triggers will do for me, anyway. Could explain what exactly you mean by "doing a join and physically populating a table is going to be very very slow"? Currently, the time required for the subsequent operation goes down from 1.7 sec to 0.003 sec if a have the joined table stored in the DB.

Comment: And what do you mean by "Why not use django as a CLI here?"?

Comment: thanks a lot for clarifying. I think the CLI approach would do the job for me. Only thing I do not understand is what you point out under "Alternatives": Currently I'm using `CHECKSUM` you see whether data has changed and I destroy and rebuild the 'join table', so where is the slow `INSERT` or `UPDATE`?

Comment: Well creating the checksum itself would take a bit of effort. Then you need to perform the join again which is said to be slow. I think you are using something like INSERT INTO jointable SELECT * FROM ... with thousands of rows being inserted this query will be slow again. I think you haven't got that much data yet