# Exceptions using django standalone with python3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Trying to use django templates in stand-alone mode.
I get these exceptions (below).
New to python, wondering if anyone would be willing to help out.

Django is used for templating in a script which is not shown here.
However the exact same exceptions appear when launching it.

```
>>> from django.template import Template, Context
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.configure()
>>> t = Template('My name is {{ my_name }}.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 86, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 182, in __init__
    engine = Engine.get_default()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/functools.py", line 472, in wrapper
    result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 88, in get_default
    django_engines = [engine for engine in engines.all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 110, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
....
....
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 137, in get_app_configs
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

My django version:

`python3 -c "import django; print(django.get_version())" ---> 1.9.7`

My python version:

`Python 3.4.3`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using django for CLI tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088702/using-django-for-cli-tool)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After calling `settings.configure()`, you must call `django.setup()`.

```
import django
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()
django.setup()
from django.template import Template, Context
t = Template('My name is {{ my_name }}.')
c=Context({'my_name': 'Mindaugas'})
t.render(c)
```

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage) for more info.