# Django: is it possible to separate DB writing functionality?

Tags: python, django, windows

I want to update DB using Windows Scheduler on a weekly basis. I have the code which extracts the data to be saved as a separate module, so I need to add DB write code there. Is it possible to run it without the server? If not, how to better run a server, make this task only and exit. I write like this now:

```
e = Employee()
e.profile_link = ...
...
e.save()

models.py:
from django.db import models

class Employee(models.Model):
    profile_link = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    ...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using django for CLI tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088702/using-django-for-cli-tool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to write a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/) and then run it whenever you want.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/573659/5098707) answer.