# Django - Passing variables from a function to another

Tags: python, django

I need some of your help please,

I'm working with `pysftp` this is working great but now I'm trying to make it work to my project in `Django` worked great in console but I want to get the data from a `form` so I won't need to use the `console` to do that.

here's my view:

```
def sftp_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = sftpForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            host = data['host']
            usuario = data['usuario']
            clave = data['clave']
            print host
            print usuario
            print clave
    else:
        form=sftpForm()
    return render(request, 'sftp.html', {'form':form})


def SFTP_subir():
    host = raw_input('ingrese el host: ') # I want form's host here.
    usuario = raw_input('ingrese el usuario: ')# I want form's usuario here.
    clave = raw_input('ingrese la clave: ')# I want form's clave here.
    try:
        transferencia = sftp.Connection(host=host, username=usuario, password=clave)

        remotepath= 'remotepath'
        localpath="mylocalpath"

        transferencia.put(localpath,remotepath)

        print ('\n' + 'Sucess.')

    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)
```

as you can see in my code `sftp_subir()` it's asking me for host,usuario and clave from console, but I want to make it work with `sftp_form()` host,usuario and clave.

Comment: Are you not able to modify the signature of your method?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean? basically I just need host's variable from one function to another @Sayse

Comment: Well the logical solution would seem to be just to pass in the values you need as function arguments, so are you not able to do that?

Comment: No, how can I do that? if you could help me I would apreciate your help :-) @Sayse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view:

```
def sftp_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = sftpForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            host = data['host']
            usuario = data['usuario']
            clave = data['clave']
            print host
            print usuario
            print clave
            SFTP_subir(host, usuario, clave) # here you invoke the function, passing variables as arguments 
    else:
        form=sftpForm()
    return render(request, 'sftp.html', {'form':form})
```

Then refactor your function to receive those params:

```
def SFTP_subir(host, usuario, clave):
    try:
        transferencia = sftp.Connection(host=host, username=usuario, password=clave)

        remotepath= 'remotepath'
        localpath="mylocalpath"

        transferencia.put(localpath,remotepath)

        print ('\n' + 'Sucess.')

    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)
```

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be a slight mixup here, you can't use `raw_input` in a django web app. If you using [Django as a CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32091771/267540) you can't use an HTTP request. As @sayse suggested in the comments, if you are using a view in a web app all you need to do is to define your second function to be one that accepts paramers

```
def sftp_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = sftpForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            host = data['host']
            usuario = data['usuario']
            clave = data['clave']
            SFTP_subir(hosts, usuario,clave)

    else:
        form=sftpForm()
    return render(request, 'sftp.html', {'form':form})


def SFTP_subir(hosts, usuario,clave):
    try:
        transferencia = sftp.Connection(host=host, username=usuario, password=clave)

        remotepath= 'remotepath'
        localpath="mylocalpath"

        transferencia.put(localpath,remotepath)

        print ('\n' + 'Sucess.')

    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)
```

Once you make this code you still have a long way to go because your SFTP method doesn't return any usefull response.

Comment: Well explained, better impossible. Worked as expected. Thanks a lot mister!

Answer (score 0):

you can do the

```
sftp.connect(...)
...
<4 lines following>
```

inside the request.method == "POST" block instead of your print statements.