# Using telethon with django: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'

Tags: python, django, multithreading, asynchronous, telethon

I want to use **Telethon** from the **django**. But when I am running it, I am getting following error:

RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.

**my code views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponse
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events

async def join(client):
    ch = '@andeh_ir'
    try:
        await client(JoinChannelRequest(ch))
        print('[+] Joined The Channel')
    except:
        print('[-] skiped')

def addChannel(request):
    api_id   =   XXXXXX
    api_hash = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    client = TelegramClient('+254716550762', api_id, api_hash )
    with client:
        client.loop.run_until_complete(join(client))
    return HttpResponse('addChannel')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44667242/ may help.

Comment: could you find the solution?

Answer (score 7):

My solution
#import asyncio

```
 import asyncio
 api_id = xxxx
 api_hash = 'b772662cf8a918bfbc39ee2aee36f6cc'
 loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
 asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
 client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash, loop=loop)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`django-telethon`](https://github.com/ali-zahedi/django-telethon) and it's support multiple sessions.

You can use the API endpoints/admin panel/interactive for signing bot and user sessions.

1. run the following command to start the server:

   ```bash
   python manage.py runserver
   ```
2. run the following command to start telegram client:

   ```bash
   python manage.py runtelegram
   ```